# Heroku and VPS firewall

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, vps, heroku

Is there any way of opening a firewall port only to Heroku hosts? Since Heroku is a cloud service, is there any way I can ensure where are they connecting from? In Heroku docs only securing conections to RDS is documented but can I secure connections to an external VPS somehow?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of the EC2 IP ranges: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1233

I'm pretty sure Heroku is all US East, so you could open up to just those.

Comment: The linked thread is no longer accessible.